# Разница суммы всех четных и нечетных элементов массива

Tags: python, массивы

Как в питон–стиле найти разницу суммы всех четных и нечетных элементов массива

Полностью задача звучит следующим образом:

Сгенерировать массив целых чисел в пределах от 0 до 100 размерности 10 на 20 (10 строк, 20 столбцов). Найти разницу суммы всех четных и нечетных элементов.

Массив сгенерировал как-то так:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, 200).reshape(10,20)
```

Comment: `diff = a[even].sum() - a[~even].sum()` где `even = (a & 1) == 0`.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 0):

например, так

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print sum([0 if x % 2 != 0 else x for x in a]) - sum([0 if x % 2 == 0 else x for x in a])
```

можно и короче

```
print sum([x if x %2 == 0 else -x for x in a])
```

А если преподаватель не понимает генераторов, тогда так

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

s = 0

for x in a:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        s+=x
    else:
        s-=x

print s
```

**UPD**

в комментах предлагают считать, что под четным элементом нужно понимать элемент, индекс которого четный. Но это стоит уточнить. В любом случае, код ещё проще (если применить срез).

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print sum(a[0::2]) - sum(a[1::2])
```

и никаких `enumerate`.

Comment: if x %2 == 0 - это как? x ведь не индекс, а значение, а вы не делали in enumerate(a)

Comment: по условию нужно проверять четность элемента, а не индекса.

Comment: с чего вы взяли?!. не сказано же "четных значений". А "четный элемент" - элемент на месте с четным порядковым номером. Впрочем я понял почему  у вас нет in enumerate

Comment: адаптировал код для Python 2/3 и добавил ещё 2 1/2 примера кода. Откатите, если что не так.

Comment: @jfs, если Вы хотите написать ответ - пишите свой ответ.

Comment: О, классно, ещё и -1 решили поставить. Супер.